# replacing div with div from an external html file

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html file and I want to replace the content of a certain `div` in it with the content\the entire div from an external html file.

I'm trying to do it with jquery but something is wrong.
Here is what I've got so far:

```
$("#originHtml").replaceWith(external.html #temp);
```

and all sorts of combinations with the `' " '`.

The code is:

```
$("#originDivId").replaceWith(external.html #temp);
```

Comment: replaceWith uses "external.html #temp" as a string, that's why I does not work and .load is the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use the jQuery [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function to load divs from different files.

```
$("#originHTML").load('external.html #temp');
```

UPDATE:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'external.html',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(html) {
        var targetdiv = $('#temp', $(html));
        $('#originHTML').replaceWith(targetdiv);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried it already and here is what I got in the console:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/***/workspace/pub/WebContent/external.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Assuming OP actually wants to replace `originHtml` then 'load()' alone will not do that. `load()` fetches the HTML and returns it into `originHtml` but does **not** replace `originHtml`.

Comment: @user1908466: Using ajax is how you load an external html file's content. Through either `ajax` directly or one of the short-hand methods, `get`, `load`, etc. The issue with Access control is a completly different problem.

Comment: @user1908466: are you loading files from your local computer? `file:///C:` seems weird.

Comment: @François Wahl: True, but the question is a little unclear since he said `I want to replace the content of a certain div in it with the content\the entire div`

Comment: @Spokey: I guess that is correct. I mainly looked at the code OP was trying to use. You got it both in your answer now so you got either propable intend covered. +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use ajax to get the html from the external.html.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("external.html", function(data){
        $("#originHtml").replaceWith($(data).find("#temp"));
    });
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is a good solution for replacing the element, but in your code `data` is not a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

To Load content from another file you have to use JQuery ajax functionality.

```
$("#originHtml").load('external.html #temp');

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#originHtml").load('external.html #temp');
});
```